# Multiple Keyword matching problems

Tags: algolia

I have a product description of the following text:
"DODGE H4C14S03706G-2G ILH48 37.06 W/ BALDOR VEM3558T"

I attempt a search "H4C1" and Algolia produces relevant results however
if I perform a search of "H4C1 VEM35" Algolia produces no results.

Is there a way to get Algolia to produce relevant results on this search?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Algolia is only doing prefix matching for the last word of the search query, which means it would only match records containing `H4C1` as a full word, and `VEM35` as a full word *or* a prefix. However `H4C1` is only a prefix of `H4C14S03706G-2G`, not a full word.

You can change the behavior by tweaking the `queryType` setting (the value you want is `prefixAll`), you can find more info in the [FAQ](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/changing-the-prefixing-behavior-with-querytype/#faq-article) and the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters/#querytype)